# How to take a derivative of tan(θ)=∂y/∂x with respect to x from both sides?

Tags: derivatives

I have a question about the following:

At 8:00 in the video below, the lecturer has shown that tan(θ) = the gradient, or 
tan(θ) = ∂y/∂x.

The lecturer then takes a derivative of both sides, 'in x'.

How is this possible, as the variable on the left is θ? I understand that the right hand side becomes the derivative of ∂y/∂x, which is ∂²y/∂x². I also get that the derivative of tan(x) = 1/cos²(x)

However, how does the derivative of tan(θ)=∂y/∂x, with respect to x become:

1/cos²(θ)*dθ/dx=∂²y/∂x²

https://youtu.be/OCq-YeByeKc?t=480

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the chain rule! 
\begin{align}
  \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \tan(\theta) &= \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \tan(\theta)\\
  &= \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x} \sec^2(\theta)\\
  &= \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x} \cdot \frac{1}{\cos^2(\theta)}
\end{align}
Notice that he writes $\frac{1}{\cos^2(\theta)}$, not $\frac{1}{\cos^2(x)}$.

Comment: Ah, that seems so obvious now, as the ∂θs cancel. I'm not exactly sure what this has to do with the chain rule, as I thought that a way to express the derivative of a composite function, which tan(θ) isn't, right?

Comment: That the $\partial \theta$'s "cancel" isn't mathematically accurate, but it's a good way to remember the chain rule (beautiful that it looks like fractions cancelling out, yes?). $\tan(\theta)$ can indeed be viewed as a composite function, where $\theta$ is a function of $x$ (i.e., $\theta = \theta(x)$.

Comment: Ah, I understand. Thanks a lot. So ∂θ/∂x is the derivative of the nested function, θ(x), while ∂/∂θ is the derivative of the composite function, which follows the chain rule. Forgive me for my ignorance, but why is it possible to assume that θ can be expressed as θ(x)? Is that apparent from the context? I can't quite (graphically, and computationally) see how θ is dependent on solely the x value.

Comment: Yes exactly! That $\theta$ depends on $x$ is apparent from his derivation. $\theta$ is defined as the inverse $\tan$ of the ratio of $\Delta y$ and $\Delta x$ (I'm guessing, haven't watched the full video), and $y$ is a function of $x$, so you end up with $\theta$ as a function of $x$.

Comment: On second thoughts, I realised that θ can be found using only the x value, given the function. So I guess that answers my question. Ah, your reply has confirmed this. Thanks so much! You can see I have only barely begun the journey into the magical world of calculus.